# $<f_a, \varphi> = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|} dx$ know that $\varphi(0)=0$ - Generalized function

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

Question : Show that $<f_a, \varphi> = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|} dx$ for any $\varphi \in D(\mathbb{R})$ for which $\varphi(0)=0$.

I am a little bit confused how to solve this problem. I know that $\varphi(0)=0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \varphi(x) dx$. Is there anyone could give me a simple hint to solve that problem? Do I have to use integration by part?

Comment: What is $f_a$? What is $a$?

Comment: @Siminore Lets see page $9$ of https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/a-guide-to-distribution-theory-and-fourier-transforms.pdf

Comment: @J-Doe Please do not share books, it's a violation of the copyright. Anyway, your question is unclear unless you define $f_a$. You should edit your question and make it clear. Did you try to use the definition of $f_a$ and some trick to split the integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution $f_a$ was defined for every $a>0$ in Strichartz's book by 
$$
\langle f_a , \varphi \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{-a} \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|}\, dx + \int_a^{+\infty} \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|}\, dx + \int_{-a}^a \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|}\, dx.
$$
If $\varphi(0)=0$, then 
$$
\langle f_a , \varphi \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{-a} \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|}\, dx + \int_a^{+\infty} \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|}\, dx + \int_{-a}^a \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|}\, dx. \tag{1}
$$
We need to prove that $x \mapsto \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|}$ is integrable, and then we simply get that $\langle f_a,\varphi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|}dx$.

The first and the second terms in (1) are obviously finite, because the support of $\varphi$ is compact. The last term in (1) is finite because $\varphi(0)=0$. Hence there is a constant $L>0$ such that $|\varphi(x)| \leq L |x|$ for $x \in [-a,a]$. As a consequence, the integrand is bounded on the domain of integration, and the improper integral converges.

Comment: Which result allow us to conclude that there exist $ L >0$...? I have already seen that before, but I don't remember the result.

Comment: Mean value theorem: $\varphi (x) - \varphi (0) = \varphi'(\xi)(x-0)$ for some $\xi$